# BottomAppBar being pushed off screen

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

When I switch from any fragment back to Shopping List with the bottom app bar, it gets pushed down off the screen and I don't know why.  Switching between the Fridge Fragment and Pantry Fragment works great, but switching from either of those back to the Shopping List Fragment pushes the bar off the screen, as shown here:

[image: GIF]

[Github repository with full code](http://www.github.com/jollygreenegiant/WannaCook)

Comment: did you try running hierarchy viewer to see your layout hierarchy? https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout

Comment: A couple of things jump out-- in the  fragment_shopping_list.xml file you do not implement `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`-- Also I don't think a `CoordinatorLayout` has an `orientation` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try with these changes for `FrameLayout` and I guess you won't need `fragment_navigation.xml` after that.

**`activity_main.xml`**:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout_for_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_shopping_cart_white_24dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You also said that it happens when you switch to `ShoppingListFragment` which has [**another `CoordinatorLayout`**](https://github.com/jollygreenegiant/WannaCook/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_shopping_list.xml) in there.

You simply change `fragment_shopping_list.xml` codes as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/shopping_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="141dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or just don't use `CoordinatorLayout` in there then try.

Comment: Thanks for looking, I implemented those changes, and the one that @Barns suggested, but it's still happening.  Updated code is pushed, if you'd like to take a look